# Problem with partitions in Kubuntu leading to pc crashing

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu

Question: Are my partitions causing problems with my Kubuntu and result in it crashing?

Problem: I think my partitions are wrong and thus my Kubuntu crashes often, which leads me to think it is a memory problem, since either my screen freezes or goes dark. Then I usually hit the restart button on my pc.

In KDE Partition Manager I deleted the windows partition after installing Kubuntu, so its marked as unallocated but still upon rebooting one of the boot options is "Windows Recovery Environment (on /dev/sdb1). Here a picture of KDE partition manager:[#first pic of partiton manager for my disc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25NQF.jpg)
Now as you can see it is highest on the list(unallocated aka where windows used to be)(not sure if it matters), but looking at the properties of all of these it just seems weird, but since I do not have time to teach myself all of the necessary aspects I need your help to tell me if something is wrong. Here are pics of the properties:
Device Properties
[Device Properties, /dev/sda](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t68TQ.jpg)
Unallocated partition properties(Old windows)
[Unallocated properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIUnF.jpg)
/dev/sda2 properties(So just under unallocated)
[/dev/sda2 (green edges, the one which reads extented)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeYDl.jpg)
/dev/sda5 partition, which to my knowledge contains my Kubuntu OS
[/dev/sda5 Kubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Z9f.jpg)
So as you can see to me it looks off, but I do not know much about how these work and unfortunately my studies take up my time and I have attention problems. Next a small back story.

I recently changed from Ubuntu 20.04 to Kubuntu 20.04 after a friends recommendation. Now when I built my pc I tried Zorin(which I managed to break so it was unusable after 1h), then windows(which never worked) until I went with Ubuntu. Now when installing Kubuntu I tried clearing all old partitions etcetera but I think my error was doing it after installation of Kubuntu.

I am very grateful for anyone who could tell me if my partitions are a problem. If they are then I hope you can also help me fix it. Thank you in advance to anyone who can help, I need to focus on studies and my pc crashing all the time does not help.

Yannick

Comment: There is nothing here to suggest there is anything wrong with your partitions. It might help if you add the output of lsblk to your question. Photos are not the best way to show this kind of thing. You can copy and paste the lsblk output and format it as code. Alternatively screenshots are much better that photos. Check journalctl  -p 3 -b -1 for error messages after a crash

Comment: Did you convert an UEFI system to old BIOS/MBR configuration. First unallocated partition looks like typical Windows ESP - efi system partition used for UEFI booting. But you show MBR(msdos) partitioning normally used with BIOS boot installs. How you boot install media is then how it installs. And Ubuntu/Kubuntu will let you use MBR with UEFI, but should not. You may want to convert drive to gpt and reinstall, if you have good backups. You then can reorganize partitions how you want. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: @PonJar  thank you for taking a look! What output of lsblk are you looking for? As for journalclt, well it seems my Kubuntu does not have it. I installed/updated systemd, but that did not help. BUT Kubuntu seems to have its own version KsystemLog that has Journald Log, but I will look at what it says if it crashes again. Thank you!

Comment: @oldfred thank you for taking a look at my problem! I did not do any converting of any sorts, I have always used my laptop(windows 10) to make a usb-stick from which I can boot the OS I want, I have not done anything more than what is directed when making a bootable usb. How do I convert my drive to gpt and reinstall? I looked at the link, but I don't really understand what I should do, I mean I can do what they say, but I'm not in the clear as to how I should play around with boots ect. If you can provide a fool proof way os reinstalling OS in a working way I would be extremely happy. Thanks!

Comment: Partitioning info in link above, that is more detailed than most. Just be sure to convert to gpt first. Then use Ubuntu live installer and choose "Something Else" and chose / partition as you created before, if you create a separate /home you also need to choose it. It auto finds the ESP & swap partitions. Swap is now optional, if not found as paritition, it creates swap file. Skip Windows screens and see Ubuntu screend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu

Comment: Also: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Hi Yannick, to solve your problem I would definitely follow @oldfred’s guidance. Just for your information running the lsblk command in a terminal would have given you most of the information in your pictures. I’m surprised that the journalctl command did not work for you. I think kubuntu uses systemd so it should work but I haven’t used kubuntu for a long time so cannot be sure